# Being not able to set multiple chrome options at the same time (blocking notifications and cookies) in selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

the code is only including blocking notifications:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)
 
           
driver.maximize_window()
                 
driver.get("https://www.hurriyet.com.tr/")
sleep(5)
```

Hello friends, I can not be able to set multiple chrome options (blocking notifications and cookies) at the same time. How can I set the blocking notifications and the cookies at the same time? Is tehere any solution I want to learn. I think that I could use somehow these together but I couldn't. :

```
"prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2} "prefs",  {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this :

```
executable_path = r"C:\\Users\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe"
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)
```

Comment: with the above code  "chrome_options=chrome_options" is an occurring problem (because we have two options), How can we do it with something like feature more pref?

Comment: No, you can have n number of chrome_options. That should not be a problem IMO.  and this is the right way to invoke driver - `driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)`   - Anyway what is the error you are seeing ?

Comment: I have something like this in my project `options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument("headless")`

Comment: row:  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)    the program is giving warning : Undefined name 'prefs' (we have 2 pref , one for blocking, other cookies) Error: NameError: name 'prefs' is not defined

Comment: That is strange, it works just fine for me in my local. How are you instantiating the driver ?

Comment: with this  I think so : driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options) 
after your code I am using  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)    row        `

Comment: There is some miscommunication I think, let me update the answer again. try the updated code

Comment: executable_path = r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)
sleep(5)
driver.get("https://www.hurriyet.com.tr/")              
sleep(5) I doesn't give error but  the web site shows notification box at the left and   cookies warning at bottom